# res.redirect is never working in NodeJS with express and passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have this simple code, the POST part of which is pretty much straight of the passport documentation:

```js
  authRouter.route('/signIn').get((req, res) => {
    res.render('signIn', {
      nav,
      props,
      title: 'Sign In'
    });
  })
  .post(passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    debug(`${chalk.redBright('authenticated')}`);
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/auth/profile');
    
  });
```

But regardless of the HTTP response (200, 304, etc), never actually redirects.  I've also tried using 
successRedirect and failureRedirect methods with the same result.

Here's my route for auth/profile:

```js
  authRouter.route('/profile')
    .all((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.user) {
        next();
        debug(req.user)
      } else {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    })
    .get((req, res) => {
      res.json(req.user);
    });

  return authRouter;
}
```

In this case, res.redirect works perfectly.

This is in Windows, but I have a nearly identical implementation in a Ubuntu project which seems to work fine.  I'm sure there's something basic I'm not understanding here, but I've been looking at it for days and I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 200 and 304 are both not statuses indicating redirects

Comment: One additional point.  When I look in the network tab, I actually see the response I'm expecting.  So I'm thinking it must be something about the way express works in windows with the browsers or something.  Any knowledge hugely welcomed!

Comment: How are you calling the POST endpoint? Is this a regular form or are you using an Ajax call?

Comment: Just a gut feeling, are you maybe sending an AJAX request? Redirects in the response of AJAX request just redirect that request and return the redirect target's content as response instead. But they don't navigate your browser. You'd need to react on the response of the call and manually navigate instead.

Comment: @leonardfactory, no...this is just a regular form submit.

Comment: could you add `if(res.headersSent) { debug('headers sent'); }` **before** res.redirect and post the output?

Comment: @leonardfactory I did     if(res.headersSent) { debug('header sent');} else {debug('nooop');}.  And got :   app:authRoutes nooop +1ms.  You're thinking that maybe headers have already be sent and that's turfing it?  Usually I get the exception stack in the terminal if so.

Comment: Yes, was thinking about something like that even if an exception is more common. May you post the full server response?

Comment: @leonardfactory.  I'm not sure what you mean, you want to see the headers from the redirect itself?  I'm not sure I can post all of it in a comment: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/auth/profile
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the answers.  I did figure it out and I feel really stupid. I was using a Bootstrap template which attached a script as part of a CSS class.  I didn't even know you could do that.  So even though I was doing a straight form post, looks like the script was doing an XHR call, which is probably why it looked like that behavior and two folks suggested that.  I really appreciate the answers.  It was pretty hard to see what was happening.  Looks like Firefox is still better for debugging in some ways.